# Is there a difference between "hold me tight" and "hold me close"?

Tags: meaning, phrases, differences

When these phrases are used as a way to request support when faced with adversity (think the seamstress & Sydney Carton at the end of *A Tale of Two Cities*, although Dickens didn't use these phrases), is there a difference between them?

I'm especially interested if one of them requests a different kind of support or implies a greater level of intimacy than the other.

Comment: In practice they'll often be used interchangeably, but you can easily establish from any dictionary that  ***close** = very **near,*** whereas ***tight** = very **firmly***. Also note that whereas our *friends* can be *close* or *tight,* we're noremally advised to keep our enemies *close*, not *tight*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"*Hold someone tight*" is, as far as I know, exclusively physical, whereas "*hold someone close*" can have both a physical and a symbolic meaning (e.g. *being close to someone's heart*).
In the face of direct (physical) adversity that might not be a great relief, though, and in that context the interpretation likely shifts to a more physical one.

To be held tight can be perceived as more intimate, but also as stifling.
To be held close does not necessitate two persons touching each other, rather that they are in close proximity.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's a difference.

"Tight" implies some level of desperation or a sense of intense "need"

"close" implies a more tender form of intimacy and emotional closeness